# C++ While Loop multiple choice condition

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am building a simple calculator, trying to do a while loop for if the user doesn't choose a correct operator so I need to have them stuck in the loop if they don't choose `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` or `%`. I know if I just put `!=` for each symbol it will just keep running if the first condition isn't met even with `||`.

here's my code some help would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char symbol;

    cout << "Please choose a number\n" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "\nPlease choose another number\n" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "\nPlease choose a operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
    cin >> symbol;

    while (symbol != '+', '-', '*', '/', '%')
    {
        cout << "\nPlease choose a VALID operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
        cin >> symbol;
    }
```

Comment: `while (symbol != '+', '-', '*', '/', '%')` is guesswork and incorrect. Refer to your C++ book for how to combine multiple conditions.

Comment: _"even with ||"_ That's because `||` is the wrong operator! Let's step through it. How would you _say_ this condition, in English, in full?

Comment: While symbol anything other than specified conditions loop.

Answer (score 3):

First, as you noted, it may be easiest to just check each operator separately. However, note that you want an **and** (`&&`) operator there, not an **or** (`||`) operator:

```
while (symbol != '+' && 
       symbol != '-' && 
       symbol != '*' && 
       symbol != '/' && 
       symbol != '%') {
    // code...
```

Alternatively, [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) may be more convenient:

```
std::string OPERATORS = "+-*/%";
while (OPERATORS.find(symbol) != std::string::npos) {
    // code...
```

Comment: will string::find still work when the data type is a char? I also noticed I forgot to add break before somebody brings that up

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs - yes. One of the overloaded variants is `size_t find (char c, size_t pos = 0) const`.

Comment: The `OPERATORS` case does copy the buffer (possibly onto the heap), and I dislike the `ALL_CAPS` name, but +1 anyhow!

Answer (score 2):

Use && (and) instead and I recommend a do-while loop to minimize code.

```
do
{
    cout << "\nPlease choose a VALID operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
    cin >> symbol;

} while (symbol != '+' && symbol != '-' && symbol != '*' && symbol != '/' && symbol != '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical operator you are looking for is `&&`.

This `while (symbol != '+', '-', '*', '/', '%')` is not the correct way for conditions in the `while` loop. You have to compare each and every condition (separate them with paranthesis) , and join those conditions with || (or) or && (and) operators.

Change this : `while (symbol != '+', '-', '*', '/', '%')` to this: `while ((symbol != '+') && (symbol!= '-')&&(symbol!= '*') &&(symbol!='/')&&(symbol!= '%'))`

Use the paranthesis for more clarity of expressions.

Also, I would recommend using the `do while` loop for such menu-based programs, where you have to run your `while` atleast once. So, try this:

```
 do
 {
   // code
 }while ((symbol != '+') && (symbol!= '-')&&(symbol!= '*') &&(symbol!='/')&&(symbol!= '%'))
```

If you use the `do while` loop method, you would have to `cin` only once.

Comment: Recommend an edit to exchange the word symbol for the word operator in the first sentence. More correct and reduces possibility for confusion with the variable `symbol` in use in the program.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to symbol in the first sentence of your answer. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: This one helped the most I didn't realize you could use brackets for each condition to keep it separate from the rest, reason I thought && was wrong was because I thought it would only break the loop if the user entered every symbol.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lightness Races in Orbit said, `||` is the wrong operator. You want to loop only if `symbol` is not equal to all of your operators:

```
while(symbol != '+' && symbol != '-' && symbol != '*' && symbol `= '/' && symbol != '%') {
    cout << "\nPlease choose a VALID operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
    cin >> symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char symbol;

    cout << "Please choose a number\n" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "\nPlease choose another number\n" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "\nPlease choose a operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
    cin >> symbol;

    while ((symbol!='+') && (symbol!='-') && (symbol!='*') && (symbol!='/') && (symbol!='%'))
    {
        cout << "\nPlease choose a VALID operator: +, -, *, /, %,\n";
        cin >> symbol;
    }

    /* do the operation */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gonzo solution.

As a beginner, this is not a good idea to try, as it involves ridiculously complex C++ features.  As an intermediate programmer, it might be entertaining and educational to figure out how it works.  As an advanced C++ programmer, I'd advise against it, as the gain in brevity at point of use is more than made up by the ridiculousness of the rest of the code.

---

When syntax lets you down, write new syntax:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct compare_with_t {
  using indexes=std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>;
  std::tuple<Ts...> values;
  template<size_t...Is, class F, class C>
  bool apply( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, C&& c, bool id) const {
    bool results[]={
      f( std::get<Is>(values) )...
    };
    return std::accumulate( std::begin(results), std::end(results), id, std::forward<C>(c) );
  }
  template<class O>
  bool operator!=( O&& o )const{
    return apply( indexes{}, [&o]( auto const&t ){ return o != t; }, [](bool a, bool b){return a&&b;}, true );
  }
  template<class O>
  bool operator==( O&& o )const{
    return apply( indexes{}, [&o]( auto&&t ){ return o == t; }, [](bool a, bool b){return a||b;}, false );
  }
  template<class O>
  friend bool operator==( O&& o, compare_with_t const& c ){
    return c==std::forward<O>(o);
  }
  template<class O>
  friend bool operator!=( O&& o, compare_with_t const& c ){
    return c!=std::forward<O>(o);
  }
};
template<class...Ts>
compare_with_t<std::decay_t<Ts>...>
compare_with( Ts&&...ts ) {
  return { std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) };
}
```

use:

```
while ( symbol  != compare_with( '+', '-', '*', '/', '%' ) ) {
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a89ee2c17511d7a).

The above requires C++14.  Further refinements would include short-circuit evaluation, not writing it at all, and possibly C++1z folds.  Oh, and `compare_with_t == compare_with_t` intersection test and similar for `!=`.

The design above creates a forwarding type `compare_with_t` that holds collection of arguments.  Then, when you `==` or `!=` with it, it does the sensible join of each comparison for you.

Techniques used that might be educational to an intermediate programmer: uniform initialization, indexes trick, unpacking tuples into an array, (ab)use of accumulate, ADL-based friend operators, auto lambdas, template factories for template classes.

Comment: well that escalated quickly

Comment: No smurf. @Yakk this is neat, but probably dangerous in a question about a really simple mechanic. I'd move the "As a beginner" caveat up to the beginning of the answer as a warning to read no further if you're looking for a simple answer.